# Exploratory Factor Analysis will not converge

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, path-model, structural-equation-modeling

I'm new to SEM, so I wanted to learn how to do an exploratory factor analysis before moving on to SEM.

I am trying to model metabolic data

```
model1 = "
v1 =~  bmi +  glu44 +  trig2 +  choladj2 +  hdl2 +  ldladj +  avzmdiabl + avzmsysbl 
"

fit1 = cfa(model1, estimator = "ML", sample.cov = cov(myData[,myvars]), sample.nobs = 125)
semPaths(fit1, "std")
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In lavaan::lavaan(model = model1, sample.cov = cov(myData[, myvars]),  :
lavaan WARNING: model has NOT converged!
```

For reference, here is the covariance matrix:

> write.csv(cov(myData[,myvars]))
>       "","bmi","glu44","trig2","choladj2","hdl2","ldladj","avzmdiabl","avzmsysbl"
>   "bmi",12.2355213277609,18.266490881459,50.7897643870314,-4.96095298885511,-10.8791177304965,-4.17866013171225,-2.67983074974671,4.52505792806484
>   "glu44",18.266490881459,185.090273556231,103.418996960486,27.9931610942249,-1.00303951367781,8.19316109422492,-2.52629179331307,10.3454407294833
>   "trig2",50.7897643870314,103.418996960486,2303.38034447822,626.086980749747,-233.310283687943,399.644123606889,-37.6416919959473,20.6869554204661
>   "choladj2",-4.96095298885511,27.9931610942249,626.086980749747,1402.80192502533,18.192654508612,1259.14478216819,18.7977710233029,102.465172239108
>   "hdl2",-10.8791177304965,-1.00303951367781,-233.310283687943,18.192654508612,130.035359675785,-65.0787740628166,20.1675278622087,18.793515704154
>   "ldladj",-4.17866013171225,8.19316109422492,399.644123606889,1259.14478216819,-65.0787740628166,1243.84478216819,6.33348530901722,79.6794579533941
>   "avzmdiabl",-2.67983074974671,-2.52629179331307,-37.6416919959473,18.7977710233029,20.1675278622087,6.33348530901722,108.249949341439,92.5715298885512
>   "avzmsysbl",4.52505792806484,10.3454407294833,20.6869554204661,102.465172239108,18.793515704154,79.6794579533941,92.5715298885512,256.564083080041

Comment: That's a confirmatory factor analysis, not exploratory.

Comment: Can you give the correlation matrix, and round it to a sensible number of digits? Also, the variances, also rounded. (It looks to me like your variances are very different, by more than a couple of orders of magnitude. This often causes problems, but I can't tell with the data).

Comment: Instead of the lavaan function, try lavaan::cfa()
You have to set the scale (marker variable or fixed latent variance), which I don't think lavaan() does for you. I could be wrong about this. Just a thought.